# Creating a listview with alphabetical sections?

Tags: android, listview

I currently have:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_contact_item, null);
    }
    BaseContact contact = this.getItem(position);
    TextView text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.contact_name);
    if (contact.getName() != null && !contact.getName().equals("")) {
        text.setText(contact.getName());
    }
    ImageView contactIcon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.contact_image);
    if ((contact.getPhotoURI() != null && !contact.getPhotoURI().toString().equals(""))) {
        Picasso.with(this.ctx).load(contact.getPhotoURI()).transform(new CircleTransform()).into(
                contactIcon);
    } else if ((contact.getPhotoURI() == null || contact.getPhotoURI().toString().equals(""))
            && (contact.getPhotoThumbURI() != null && !contact.getPhotoThumbURI().toString()
            .equals(
                    ""))) {
        Picasso.with(this.ctx).load(contact.getPhotoThumbURI()).transform(new CircleTransform()).into(
                contactIcon);
    } else {
        Picasso.with(this.ctx).load(R.drawable.contact_no_picture).transform(new CircleTransform()).into(
                contactIcon);
    }

    return convertView;
}
```

I would like to replicate what the people app has similar to this: 
[image: screenshot]

Now, judging by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4777272/android-listview-with-different-layout-for-each-row).

I would be able to have a custom view dedicated to just the section, but I don't quite grasp how to figure out whether a position would be a section or not, also if a section is empty, how would it be omitted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About multi rows:

You must override two methods of your adapter:

```
   @Override
   public int getItemViewType(int position) {
     //your logic. as example:
       return getItem(position).getTitle()==null?0:1
   }

   @Override
   public int getViewTypeCount() {
       return 2;
   }
```

And then in your getView():

```
           public View getView(etc...){
              if(convertView == null){
              switch(getItemViewType(position)){
                  //ugly things happen here…
                  case 0: //create view 0 + viewHolder0 and other stuff
                      break;
                  case 1: //create view 1 + viewHolder1 and other stuff
                      break;
              ....
              return covertView;
           }
```

If you don't wanna write custom adapter just use StickyListHeaders

https://github.com/emilsjolander/StickyListHeaders

Comment: But how exactly would I know to place a header at x position to show a start of a new letter?

Comment: Add field to your BaseContact class

Comment: How would that help? I already know the name of the person I am trying to add, I need to know how to programmatically decide whether I should add a header or an item.

Comment: Add field to your BaseContact class - 'header'. And in getItemViewType () check if it is not null it is a header. And of course you should add objects to your list of data which have only header